# yii submit restyle to jquery-ui

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, yii

I am working with yii framework, and jquery-ui, I would like to change the yii submit buttons to a jquery-ui style button.  ( I would like them all to look the same.)
This is the code I am trying to change, and i have tried added all the they jquery button classes to this class, but that didn't work.  I was wondering is there a simple way to make all buttons to look like the jquery library buttons?

```
<div class="row buttons" >
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Login'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: have you added  jquery-ui.css ?

Comment: or try this ..  $(function() {
    $( "input[type=submit],button" )
      .button();     
  });

Comment: @ramamoorthy_villi, Yes i have. That second comment worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
<script>

$(function() { $( "input[type=submit],button" ) .button(); });

</script>
```